# Should I inherit when a function in a child class might be left blank?

Tags: c++, inheritance

This question is a bit generic, but I'm not really sure if it is a good practice or should I think about other solution. Should I include in a base class a function which is going to be in some of child classes but not in all of them? Because if I do that, I should leave blank the function in the class I don't need it and that doesn't seem to be a clean practice.

Comment: What's the alternative?

Comment: It probably depends on the particular case. Do you have a concrete example of such a situation?

Comment: probably not. It could be dangerous. Like if a function expects all objects of type X to have Y, what happens when Y is "left blank"? It _might_ be better to have a second level of abstraction. eg base object A without Y and a derived object B that only adds Y from which all objects needing Y would be derived.

Comment: The concrete case is, I have three classes, truck, container and product. All of them have volume(float) and a function that returns its volume, but only trucks and containers can "contain" products and other containers. The idea would be to create a base class with the volume and also add a contain? function, but in the product class that wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Maybe it should be a better option to inherit just the volume and make a generic class that can represent both a truck and a container cause in the end they have the same behaviour.